# Write file to location other than SDcard using Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, storage

Is there any other way to write a file somewhere else than on the SD card?

I tried many different path on the filesystem but fopen always return NULL, except for any file that I write/read inside the /sdcard/...

Is there something else equivalent to:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

That allow you to write like on the file system or something?

Comment: Answered in this link:<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992953/file-operations-in-android-ndk?lq=1>

Answer (score 21):

1. You can always access the directory
   in which your app is placed.

   This directory is usually :

   `data/data/<Your_package_name_usually
   com.android.appName>/files/<your_filename>`

   but better use `getFilesDir()` to
   ensure valid filepath with future
   version changes of android.
2. If  you wanna use external storage
   instead, make sure you place this
   line of code in your app manifest to
   gain permission.

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   ```

   Then use the sdcard directory :

   `getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
   //usually : /sdcard/<your_filename>`
3. Otherwise, you can root the device
   and gain access to the whole
   filesystem. But you'll have to
   request all of your app users to get
   root access on their device before
   using your application. Some games
   use this way of doing things, but I
   wouldn't recommend it. If you still
   wanna do this, lookup `Superuser`
   app for android, it's free and
   trustable.

Once you have the android directory, just create a JNI native method that receive a jstring parameter, and you set it up inside your native code. Convert it into a std::string, and you'll be ready to use it with fopen().

```
//Inside your java activity
File f = this.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(); 
LibLoader.setupArchiveDir(f.toString());

//Inside your JNI wrapper
JNIEXPORT bool JNICALL Java_com_android_appName_LibLoader_setupArchiveDir(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj, jstring dir)
{
        const char* temp = env->GetStringUTFChars(dir, NULL);
    std::string stringDir(temp);

        // Will be receive as a std::string inside C++ code 
    MyNativeObjectInC++->SetupArchiveDir(stringDir);
}
```

---

**Edit :**

You might need to manualy creates the /files in C before being able to use it on the first time :

`int result_code = mkdir("/data/data/com.app/files/", 0770)`

Cheers !

Comment: what flags `0770` contains in the last code sample.
`mkdir("/data/data/com.app/databases", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IWOTH | S_IXOTH);` doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 5):

You have access to two locations from within your app, the SDCard and a special data directory for your app.  Any other place is off limits unless you have root access.

Comment: Where is the location of that "special data directory"? Cuz I do presume that not all phone have an SDcard... So the /sdcard/ dir. is not reliable. TIA

Comment: You can ask the OS where the directory is in Java using the following commands:

mContext.getFilesDir();
mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null);

You should favor external storage for large objects since the device may have limited internal storage.

Comment: I have root access to the device. Could you please explain how can i access the file system. Trying to open a file in system is not working for me. Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785497/accessing-root-files-system-dev-from-a-native-library-in-android-applicatio)