# GetFilesDir() from NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is there a way to get the application's directory to save private data to a file for my application directly from the NDK? In other words, I need an equivalent of the Java function mContext.getFilesDir().

I have noted that other posts such as this one:
[Android NDK Write File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731314/android-ndk-write-file)

mention what is the 'usual' place for this directory to be. But for it to be correct in all versions and all devices, an equivalent system call is surely necessary.

I am currently using a NativeActivity and no Java at all.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `NativeActivity` then you have access from native code to an `ANativeActivity` instance (see  `<ndk_root>/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/android/native_activity.h`) which has `internalDataPath` and `externalDataPath` members.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately both internalDataPath and externalDataPath are NULL during runtime..? Any ideas? This is when running on a google nexus S device.

Comment: ok according to this link: http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/e250fc392fb0e145?pli=1 it is a known bug with android 2.3.x and it is fixed in 3.0. Great! So I'll need to look into implementing jni just for this...

Comment: I went down that same route and, after looking at the spread of installed device OS versions realized that I simply couldn't ignore v2.1. So NativeActivity became a non-issue. As it turns out, implementing a full JNI shim is pretty straightforward, and has the added advantage that whenever you find something that NativeActivity has left out, you;re already set up to add it.

Answer (score 12):

I have custom helper class for accessing various paths, for the data directory I do this:

1. Read `/proc/self/cmdline` or `/proc/**MyPID**/cmdline`
2. Append the results from #1 to `/data/data/`

**Example results:**

```
/data/data/com.yourcompany.yourproduct/
```

Comment: For those wondering how to get the `MyPID`, you could simply substitute that with "self', i.e. read `/proc/self/cmdline` and that will save you a bit of extra hassle.

Comment: @MultiColourPixel Good point, I have updated the answer to show both.