# get application name from NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to get name of my android application from the native side somethin like that:

```
 android.content.context context=(android.content.context) this;//current activiy
 Resources appR =context.getResources();
 String packageName=context.getPackageName();
 int id=appR.getIdentifier("app_name","string",packageName );
 CharSequence txt = appR.getText(id);
```

my native code like that:

```
  jstring Java_com_AnalyticToolC_AnalyticToolActivity_JNISendData(JNIEnv* env,jobject entryObject,jobject contxt)
 {

   char *realAppName;
 realAppName=(char *)malloc(16 * 1024);
 jclass android_content_Context =(*env)->GetObjectClass(env, contxt);
    jmethodID midGetPackageName = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, android_content_Context, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String");
 jstring packageName=(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, contxt, midGetPackageName);
jmethodID midGetResources = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, android_content_Context, "getResources", "()L");
    jobject jResource=(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, context, midGetResources);

   jclass resource_Class=(*env)->GetObjectClass(env, jResource);
   jmethodID midGetIdentifier = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, resource_Class, "getIdentifier", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String)I");
   jstring app_name=(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"app_name");
   jstring TypeName=(*env)->NewStringUTF(env,"string");
   int id=(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, jResource, midGetIdentifier,app_name,TypeName,packageName);

  jmethodID midGetAppName = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, resource_Class,"getText","(I)Ljava/lang/String");
  jstring appName=(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, jResource, midGetAppName,id);   

  realAppName=(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, appName, NULL);
}
```

and i just pass the activity to my native methon from java code.

and i don't have a chance to write this code in java class then call it form my NDK application 
I'm trying a lot to pass a context object as jobject to my native code but it always crash.
dose any one have any idea?

Comment: your problem is "()Ljava/lang/String". You should use this "()Ljava/lang/String;"

Comment: [the simplest way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6284443/192373) is to read `/proc/MyPID/cmdline`.

Comment: Relevant http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/145869/8984

Answer (score 14):

Reflected Java access in C is ugly, ugly, ugly, just like you've demonstrated. Pass the app name as an extra string parameter.

EDIT: OK, you want reflection, reflection you'll get.

Your native method belongs to class `AnalyticToolActivity`. As a nonstatic class method, it has a `this` pointer on every call. Unlike C++ and Java methods, this pointer is passed explicitly as the second parameter. The method has two mandatory parameters - a `JNIEnv *` and a `jobject`. The second one corresponds to the `this` pointer of the Java object.

So if your `AnalyticToolActivity` is a subclass of `Activity` - quite likely - the `entryObject` parameter is an instance of `Activity`, meaning it's an instance of `Context`. So get rid of the third parameter (`contxt`), and your JNI code can go like this:

```
jclass android_content_Context =(*env)->GetObjectClass(env, entryObject);
//or use FindClass

jmethodID midGetPackageName = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,
    android_content_Context,
    "getPackageName",
    "()Ljava/lang/String;");

jstring packageName=(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, entryObject, midGetPackageName);
```

and so forth.

Comment: I know it's ugly, ugly so ugly  but this is the case, I need to access the SharedPreferences object also, if anyone can help  I really appreciated

Comment: Wording suggests your native method belongs to your activity class. The activity *is* a subclass of context. If your native method is static, remove that; then treat the `this` pointer (AKA `entryObject`) as a Context reference.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you, but my native method is not static method and you mean (jobject entryObject) should be my pass object "activity from java side"

Comment: thanks, I solve it problem with method signature you have to put ; if your method will return object not primitive type object, it should looks like "()Ljava/lang/String;"

Comment: brilliant answer...learnt more in that paragraph than from an entire book

Comment: should be "()Ljava/lang/String;"

Answer (score -4):

Why do you need to do so from the NDK? Perhaps it would be more useful for us to help you debug the problem passing a context object, and then you could just pass the app name as a string.

Comment: i do that cause i have a my C lib which will use by other native application so i need to use the application name in my C lib, anyway i will update the Question with my native code.