# Can't write to the file in android emulator

Tags: java, android, c, android-emulator, java-native-interface

### *Problem Description*

I am writing application for Android and use native code, And test it on ***Android-Emulator***. In order to see what happens in JNI code I create file in Android ***/data/LogTest/*** folder and write my log information in it.

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("/data/LogTest/Log.txt"", "w");
// .... 
// Write some logs to file ...
// ....
```

When I run in the first time Android application everything goes Okay, I can see logs in Log.txt file. But when I close Android application and run it again nothing happening. Like application can't write Logs to the file second time.

### *Self Ideas*

***I think that the main reason of this problem is that***, when I create file at first time the creator application Name is for ex. 456 after when I try to write some more information to file application Name is for ex. 856 and so ***application 856 can't write to file that have created application 456***.

### *Question*

1. ***How I can launch application with same name, in order Android let me to write to file in second time.***
2. ***Or maybe the main reason o problem is not that Application every time get rundom names.***

Comment: Just a side note, you can also send log messages to logcat through the liblog.

Comment: You have to include the log.h file and and liblog to your make file after that you can use __android_log_write() in your code. Here is one blogpost that goes into detail. http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/08/android-ndk-logging/

Comment: @ba__friend Thanks for your support, your answer is very useful for me and I learn new thing from your comment, but it is not actually what I want, I need to write to Log.txt

Comment: check if `fopen` failed: `if (pFile == NULL) perror("fopen");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not allowed to write in that folder. Read through the answers here. Either use the sdk card or your application directory to store files.

[File Operations in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992953/file-operations-in-android-ndk)

Comment: i love the link. File Operations in Android NDK

Answer (score 1):

your code is generating an error on my emulator. Yet you say

> When I run in the first time Android
>   application everything goes Okay, I
>   can see logs in Log.txt file

Perhaps you could send us more of your code, so we can reproduce the error. 
This is my attempt at reproducing your question

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jni.h>
#include<android/log.h>//allow android logging
#include<errno.h>//for errors
#include<string.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "DEO MSG"//all my logs are labeled with this
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

void Java_com_deo_MyActivity_writeLogFileUsingC(JNIEnv * env, jobject thisObject)
{   char filename[]="/data/LogTest/Log.txt";
    LOGE("native method started");//is used exactly like the usual printf()
    FILE * pFile;
    LOGE("trying to open file for writing");
    pFile= fopen(filename, "w");
    if(pFile==NULL)
    {
        LOGE("Failed to open the file %s in mode 'w'.(DETAILS)%s ",filename,strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        LOGE("trying to write to file");
        fprintf(pFile,"logExample  "); //example of a log.
        fclose(pFile);//safely close our file
        LOGE("file writing done");
    }
}
```

The error it generates in logcat is

```
ERROR/DEO MSG(816): Failed to open the file /data/LogTest/Log.txt in mode 'w'.(DETAILS)No such file or directory
```

I think my problem with your code may be permissions. Describe it more for us.
 
PS:

- i personally prefer using the logcat for debugging compared to log files