# android seems not support syscall,open()

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, linux-kernel

android is a kind of linux,and it must support the posix.But,when it seems not support the syscall,open().
Here is the code for testing,and i compile it via NDK:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

void main(){
    int fd;
    char pathname[128] = "/data/pwrite.txt";
    fd = open(pathname, O_WRONLY);
    if(fd==-1){
        printf("open fail.\n");

    }
    perror("/data/pwrite.txt");
}
```

and the following is the prompt that comes from android:

```
kaiwii@ubuntu:~$ adb shell /data/pwrite/test1
open fail.
/data/pwrite.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Instead of just printing `"open fail"`, print the actual error instead. You can do that either by printing out `errno` or the string returned by `strerror`, or using the `perror` function.

Comment: kaiwii@ubuntu:~$ adb shell /data/pwrite/test1
open fail.
/data/pwrite.txt: No such file or directory

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg i use the perror to print the error,and the above is what it prompt.But,i feel confused that why not the open() create the file yet.thx

Comment: have you visited [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1992953/996493) ? @kaiwiiho

Comment: actucally,my question seems a little bit different from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in the flags - you only use `O_WRONLY`. But if a file does not exist you should also create it using `O_CREAT` flag. So if a file does not exist you should call:

```
fd = open(pathname, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not the `syscall open()` but the fact that your are trying to access `/data`. This folder is accessible only for rooted mobiles or in the emulator. Have you tried to put the file into the `/sdcard` folder?