# Quickest way to take screenshot on android?

Tags: android, screenshot, android-service

I am trying to take screenshot an a **rooted** android phone locally. I want to take screenshot of **other activites**, via a service. The only requirement is that the screenshot should be atmost ~ 100ms.

I try

```
java.lang.Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > " + raw + "\n");
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
os.close();
process.waitFor();
```

but as i try to write it to a file, it takes a bit too long!

Also, as I am trying to do this locally on the phone, without connecting it to the PC.

Comment: as i said, I am trying to do this locally on the phone.

Comment: You might get better performance using Android NDK. This post has some stuff related to file operations with NDK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992953/file-operations-in-android-ndk

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported and may or may not work on all devices. You might also get something that is not in a format you are expecting. If you are using a 4.0+ device you can see how they implement the system screenshot functionality and emulate that. There are also a couple of small utilities in AOSP, screencap and screenshot, you might want to look at their code (in `frameworks/base/cmds`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb command to take the screenshot
   adb shell screencap -p /mnt/sdcard/screen.png
and execute it programatically from the applicaiton