# C++ File IO in android studio

Tags: android, file-io

```
std::ofstream fout;
fout.open("/sdcard/AudioMixer/output.pcm");
if(!fout.is_open()) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,"__main","output file is not opened");
    return -1;
}
fout.close();
```

i wrote this code on c++ and call function using JNI
but fout.is_open() always returns false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Operations in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992953/file-operations-in-android-ndk)

Comment: Do you have "/sdcard/AudioMixer/output.pcm" file?