# Android: How to access audio files from Mediastore in a native libary (c++)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, mediastore

I am working on an app that manipulates audio files using the native library oboe. This is my first project using the Android NDK, I am also new to C++.

So far I managed to open files from the asset folder, this works without a problem. I also uderstand I can open files from elsewhere (if I have the path) using fopen as described here: [File Operations in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992953/file-operations-in-android-ndk)

But how can I handle files from the Mediastore, where you have Uris instead of concrete paths? I can't seem to find any information on how to handle this? What would be a feasible approach? Are there any best practices? I know how this works in Java/Kotlin, but how can I access the store from native code, or how can I hand them over?

Comment: are you looking for some research material or examples ? If you are looking for help with your coding, please post your code.

Comment: I am actually just looking for a hint at how to do what I described in the question since I can't find any information on the topic. I didn't add any code since my problem here is actually I don't know *what* to code or where to start.